# Is it possible to enforce a call to a method inside of another method in Java?

Tags: java, android

I've seen that in Android, sometimes when you override a method, it always come with a call to the super class, and every once in a while, some of you can't remove this call, because the IDE show's a compile time error. So that question is, Is it possible to enforce a call to a method inside of another? And if it is, how do I do that?

Comment: What error are you getting? You should always include your errors in your post.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I just want to know if it is possible to enforce a call for a method inside of another method. The thing I said about compile errors in Android Studio is that it sort of proves that such a thing is possible, but I have no ideia of how it's done.

Comment: I don't think you can enforce a call to ANY method, but as you mentioned your self, it's possible to enforce the call to super. I wonder if it's part of the SDK and not some syntax in Java.

Comment: I assume you mean you get a runtime exception and a warning in your IDE. There is no way to enforce at compile time that you call `super.method()` when you override `method`.

Comment: I see. Maybe its something with Android Studio. I'll leave this question opened just to see what others think about it.

Comment: The only error you would get is if the method *returned* the super call, and you didn't return a value in it's place. Forgetting/refusing to call a method inside of another method doesn't cause any compile time errors. There is nothing in the language specification that states you must call a method in another method. If anything, it would give you logical errors, but not compile time errors.

Comment: A code sample would be great for this question.

Comment: I'm just going use `onCreate()`, as an example. Here is what happens when you do [`super.onCreate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: This is an IDE feature, you probably should look into your Linter tasks. https://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/run-lint-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 3):

Youn can use the android support annotations for this. First you need to use the support annotations in your project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

Use the `@CallSuper` annotation.

You can write your own annotation processor for this purpose to make customs behaviors

See more:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/annotations-custom.html

Comment: This is what you're looking for.  The annotation causes the compile error if you don't call the super.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you get a runtime exception and a warning in your IDE. There is no way to enforce at compile time that you call `super.method()` when you override `method`.

One thing you can do is flip a `boolean` to `true` in the superclass method.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    private boolean superCalled = false;

    public void foo() { superCalled = true; }

    void bar() {
        foo();
        if (!superCalled)
            throw new IllegalStateException("You did not invoke super.foo()");
    }
}
```

Thanks to @VinceEmigh for pointing out that `onCreate` works in this way by setting a `boolean` called `mCall` to `true`. [Here is the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165249/is-it-possible-to-enforce-a-call-to-a-method-inside-of-another-method-in-java/36165571?noredirect=1#comment59968360_36165571).

This works in android because you should not call `onCreate` directly - it is the android system, not you, that determines when `onCreate` is called. The writers of the android system can just ensure that the `boolean` is always checked after every call.

Comment: [Seems like it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29). `mCall` is set to `true` at the end of the method.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks, I didn't realise `Activity` was available for us all to read. I'll put this in my answer.

Comment: It is called the Android Open Source Project for a reason :)

Comment: @cricket_007 I've been programming android apps for about 2 years. I really should have known that!

Comment: Also 2 years, but I like [downloading the source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and just copying layouts sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Well, that call to `super` is to utilize inheritance. It lets you get away with that call so that you don't have to implement everything that the method with the same name in your super class has already implemented. Which is quite great.

About calling another method from inside a method. You are always going it in some form or the other. Functions can have helper methods; even calling a mere constructor can be called calling a method from inside a method.